# Laravel: orWhere in a loop

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get a few `orWhere` clauses in a query depending the amount of a variable, but the result of the query I get right now, is not what I need.

```
$names = Input::get('name');
$query = DB::table('table')
->where('name', '=', 'something');
foreach ($naam_categorie as $naam){
    $query->orWhere('id',$naam));
}

$query->update(array('value' => 1));
```

I am updating at a specific where clause, to `value = 1`. How do I get the rest of the value's to 0?

What is exactly going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the **return value** of `get()` and not the query builder instance:

```
$result = $query->get();
var_dump($result);
```

Regarding the input I'd do it like this:

```
$names = Input::get('name');
$query = DB::table('table');
foreach($names as $name){
   $query->orWhere('id', $name);
}
$result = $query->get();
```

### Edit

For the update the simplest thing is probably to first set all to `0` and then the ones that match to `1`:

```
DB::table('table')->update(array('value' => 0));

$names = Input::get('name');
$query = DB::table('table');
foreach($names as $name){
   $query->orWhere('id', $name);
}
$query->update(array('value' => 1));
```

Comment: The thing with the input is, it contains multiple values and it depends on the amount of the `$x` variable

In the blade the **name** is: `name[]`

Comment: I got that hence the `foreach`. What's the `$x` variable? Isn't it the number of names in the array?

Comment: Yes it is. $x = the amount of values.

Comment: Then you actually shouldn't need that. Just try my code ;)

Comment: Yes you can just remove the first where. The query builder is smart enough to only put `OR` and `AND` operators between two wheres ;)

Comment: Is there a way to just get the column ID from the `$result`?

Comment: Yes you can call `$result = $query->lists('id')` and you will get an array of the id's in the result

Comment: What if I wanted the same query but the results where it's **NOT** the same but keep both?

Comment: You mean `where('id', '!=', $name)` ?

Comment: yes. But when I have both(as an update query), it wont update anymore.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Either edit your question and show me your code or ask a new one. Thanks